# Entity Framework calculated property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have following classes in EF6

```
Items
-------------
public int       ItemID
public string    ItemName
public decimal   ItemPrice
public virtual   List<ListPricesItems> ListPricesItems
public decimal   ItemDiscountedPrice (need to calculate this)

ListPrices
----------------
public int    ListID
public string ListDescription
public Date   ListValidUntilDate


ListPricesItems
-----------------
public int        LPRID
public int        ListID
public int        ItemID
public decimal    ItemDiscountedPrice
```

What I need to do is to have ItemDiscountedPrice in Items that does the following

```
        [NotMapped]
        public decimal ItemDiscountedPrice
        {
            get
            {

               if(ListPricesItems.ListPrices.ListValidUntilDate > Date.Now()){

                   return ListPricesItems.ItemDiscountedPrice ?? ItemPrice;

               }

            }
        }
```

Is this possible to do ? If discount policy is still active, check if ItemDiscountedPrice is null and give standard ItemPrice if it is null.

UPDATED

```
public partial class Items
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int ItemID { get; set; }


        public string ItemName { get; set; }


         [Column(TypeName = "money")]
        public decimal? ItemPrice { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ListPricesItems> ListPricesItems { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public decimal ItemDiscountedPrice 
        {
            get
            {

                return ......................

            }
        }


    }


    public partial class ListPrices
    {
        [Key]
        public int ListID { get; set; }

        public string ListDescription { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public DateTime? ListValidUntilDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ListPricesItems> ListPricesItems { get; set; }

    }

    public partial class ListPricesItems
    {
        [Key]
        public int LPRID { get; set; }

        public int? ListID { get; set; }

        public int? ItemID { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "money")]
        public decimal? ItemDiscountedPrice { get; set; }

        public virtual ListPrices ListPrices { get; set; }
    }
```

[image: Here is what I get on ListPricesItems]

Comment: Please post some of your real code, what you have posted doesn't make sense. For instance, where is `ListPrices.ListValidUntilDate` coming from? The only `ListPrices` in your sample is the name of a type, not a property. So that expression would not compile.

Comment: it should be ListPricesItems.ListPrices.ListValidUntilDate on the Items class - i updated the question

Comment: I cant get ListPricesItems.ListPrices.ListValidUntilDate. How can I get it from Items class ? It wont give me any querying options like FirstOrDefault or Where.

Comment: You really need to post the code of your classes. The summary you've posted doesn't tell us how a ListPricesItems has a ListPrices member. (All I see are four scalar properties in this type as you have posted it).Please post the actual code of these classes.

Comment: FirstOrDefault and Where are for List type. ListValidUntilDate is not list(its date). btw your question is vague . i dont see ListPrices in ListPricesItems

Comment: The classes are in different language so I tried to translate them in the simple way. I updated the code. I hope it is clearer now. What I wont to do is to check if the ListPrices is still active (Date has not passed) and if it is, get the ItemDiscountedPrice from <ListPricesItems>.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I know FirstOrDefault and Where are for List type but I cant get ICollection<ListPricesItems> as a List - I can only get a Count, Equals and such.

Comment: you can convert it to list .`ListPricesItems.ToList()`.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary  There is no .ToList() - that is the problem - take a look at this image [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Pj7iJ.png)

Comment: .ToList() is for Linq. you must have this in top of your .cs file `using System.Linq;`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary - It was really just "using System.Linq;" - thanks a lot. Please add an answer so I can accept it as the right one.

Comment: but your question is not related to this answer. discussion went somewhere else in comments.so i dont think it will be usefull for others. but still you can give answer to your own question. you can accept it 2 days later. ;). btw im glad that i helped and thats enough for me :)